# How much force needed to keep this together?

Tags: physics

Let's consider the following situation:
There are 3 identical cylinders each with a weight of 20 tons.

The 3rd one is put over the other 2 like in the picture (but the bottom 2 do touch each other). The 2 bottom ones are on the floor, on Earth in normal environmental conditions.

[image: Picture]

Ignoring any friction, what force is necessary on the sides of the 2 bottom cylinders to prevent the 3rd one from pushing them outwards and falling between them ?

I have a vague idea on how to calculate this but I really don't remember if there are other things to be considered.

Comment: What is your "vague idea"? Also, this is _not_ [tag:algebraic-geometry].

Comment: The weight from the upper one will be evenly distributed to the 2 below. Then each one will be combined with the one of the lower cylinders. About the category, if there's something else that fits tell me.

Comment: I put the [tag:physics] tag on it, because whatever else it may be, that's definitely it. So, to get to solving: what forces are acting on each of the three cylinders, how large are they and what direction are they in? Draw a diagram (at least for the top one and one of the two bottom ones) and show us. Then we can start working.